# Местоимения он и тот

Tags: местоимения

> Тогда кондитер дал ему сахарное варенье вместо меда, потому что **он**
>   у него закончился.

По-моему, вместо *он* лучше *тот*. Так ли?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Тогда кондитер дал ему сахарное варенье вместо меда, потому что **он у него** закончился.

"Он у него" - не есть хорошо. Уж лучше употребить слово *мед* два раза:

**Тогда кондитер дал ему сахарное варенье вместо меда, потому что мед у него закончился.**

Думаю, в этом контексте *тот* не может быть употреблено для указания на неодушевленный предмет.

Тот

> Указывает на последнее из названных в предшествующей речи лиц мужского пола; он. Я взглянул на отца, тот молчал. ([Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82))

Answer (score 3):

Вряд ли это возможно по отношению к мёду, который упомянут в изменчивом количестве (и вовсе исчез - существует абстрактно), не имеет формы и т. д. Проблема - в неодушевлённости и бесформенности при такой функции местоимения "тот" (со ссылкой на людей такой проблемы не бывает):

> Субстантивированные *одушевленные* тот, та служат для анафорической
> отсылки к **лицу**, которое не является смысловой темой текста...
>
> *В редких случаях* антецедент может быть неодушевленным...

http://rusgram.ru/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#211

(см. 2.1.6 Субстантивированные тот, та в анафорической функции)

Надо искать другие пути:

> И взамен закончившегося мёда кондитер дал ему сахарный сироп.

Answer (score 3):

Убираем лишние слова и повторы:

**Тогда кондитер дал ему сахарное варенье вместо меда, который закончился.**